# Parse push notification tutorial problems - android studio

Tags: parse-platform, gradle, notifications, dependencies, push

I have solved a few issues that may help others run the [Parse Push Notification  tutorial](https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_push/android/native/existing) successfully:

**Download the SDK, drug the Parse-*.jar file into "libs" folder, add dependencies to Gradle -** This seems easy, but there is some missing information for beginners. These are the three things I found that made everything work:

1. There is only one file you need to touch - find it in the downloaded SDK.
2. It is not necessarily that you have a "libs" folder. If you don't, you need to create it. In Android Studio, you will have to move from "Android" view of your project, to "Project Files", and in the same folder as "build" and "src/main" you have to add a "libs" folder. Then, you paste there the file, right-click on it, and press "add as library". Only then, this Jar is added.
3. Dependencies - you will have to add in the build.gradle "Module", not in the first appearance of "dependencies" in the file where the paths are, but rather in the second where "compile" would appear.
   It is important **not** to add redundant dependencies, or else you will get a gradle error (see below). To prevent that, you should avoid for example, from writing

> ```
> dependencies {
>        compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.2.1'
>        compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
>        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-*.jar')
> }
> ```

The first two compile dependencies cannot co-exist. 
It may seem harmless, but it isn't.

This is the error you will get when adding redundant dependencies:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':ParseStarterProject:dexDebug'. > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_76\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Answer (score 0):

Instead of dragging and droping the sdk files add it from module settings
[image: Right Click on the app folder of your project]

[image: on the dependencies tab click on the green plus icon]
[image: copy the parse sdk files to the build directory of your folder and add it]

Answer (score 0):

This type of error is due to jar missmatch and two times jar added.kindly remove second entry that u have made.

remove this:     compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'